# Gnuplot script will not work but manually inputting commands works fine

Tags: gnuplot

When I plot something manually it works fine, however when I put it into a script it gives an error.
I have data files named *g000000, g000007, g000008, g000010*...etc corresponding to different time-steps of a simulation.
Each data file is an ascii file with many columns of data. I would like to make a plot of x vs y (columns 1 and 2) and use column 17 to color the data.

Here is the code I have:

```
set term gif size 1000,600
set xr [-0.05:0.05]
set yr [-0.05:0.05]
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"

filelist = system('ls g000*')
do for [file in filelist] {
set output 'gasFe.'.(file[2:*]).'.gif'
plot file u 1:2:17 w d lc palette title (file)
}
```

However I get an error saying

```
;

set output 'gasFe.'.(file[2:*]).'.gif';
plot file u 1:2:17 w d lc palette title (file);

line 11: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

;
set output 'gasFe.'.(file[2:*]).'.gif';
plot file u 1:2:17 w d lc palette title (file);


line 11: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
...etc
```

However doing this manually using the same commands above without using a script works fine! So what is the problem???

Comment: What is `w d`, do you mean `w p` (`with points`)? Are the ranges correct? Do you have 17 columns? Does the following work: `plot 'g000000' u 1:2:17 w p lc palette`?

Comment: w d means with dots (plots a dot rather than a plus symbol which is what you get w p). The ranges are correct. Yes I have more than 17 columns. The code segment you suggested does work (w p and w d both work, and plot my data-points as a "+" and "." respectively). As I said...it's strange, I don't understand why the script won't work